# tikz - Add more parameter to macro not work

Tags: tikz-pgf

refer to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/521265/70324) SO, I wish to add one more matrix to draw another cubic, so wish to change the code but use parameter to setup the RGB coordinate (change matCC to matPC, and use it as parameter). I change it as below but compile failure!

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\def\matPC{{0.257, 0.504, 0.098},% 
    {-0.148, -0.291, 0.439},%
    {0.439, -0.368,0.071}}%
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{RGBvec}{4}{% r,g,b,mat
    \begingroup%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myY}{16+{#4}[0][0]*#1+{#4}[0][1]*#2+{#4}[0][2]*#3}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myCb}{128+{#4}[1][0]*#1+{#4}[1][1]*#2+{#4}[1][2]*#3}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myCr}{128+{#4}[2][0]*#1+{#4}[2][1]*#2+{#4}[2][2]*#3}%
    \edef\pgfmathresult{\myCr,\myCb,\myY}%
    \pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult\endgroup%
}%

\begin{document}
    \tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{110}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[bullet/.style={circle,inner
        sep=2pt,fill},line cap=round,line join=round,
    RGB coordinate/.code args={(#1,#2,#3),#4)}{\pgfmathparse{RGBvec(#1,#2,#3,#4)}%
        \tikzset{insert path={(\pgfmathresult)}}},font=\sffamily,thick]
    \begin{scope}[tdplot_main_coords,scale=1/40]
    \draw[-stealth] (0,0,0) coordinate (O) -- (280,0,0) coordinate[label=below:Cr] (Cr);
    \draw[-stealth]  (O) -- (0,280,0) coordinate[label=below:Cb] (Cb);
    \draw[-stealth]  (O) -- (0,0,280) coordinate[label=left:Y] (Y);
    \path [RGB coordinate={(255,255,255),\matPC}] node[bullet,draw,fill=white] (white){}
    [RGB coordinate={(0,0,0),\matPC}] node[bullet] (black){}
    [RGB coordinate={(255,0,0),\matPC}] node[bullet,red] (red){}
    [RGB coordinate={(0,255,0),\matPC}] node[bullet,green] (green){}
    [RGB coordinate={(0,0,255),\matPC}] node[bullet,blue] (blue){}
    [RGB coordinate={(255,0,255),\matPC}] node[bullet,magenta] (magenta){}
    [RGB coordinate={(255,255,0),\matPC}] node[bullet,yellow] (yellow){}
    [RGB coordinate={(0,255,255),\matPC}] node[bullet,cyan] (cyan){};
    \draw (red) -- (black) -- (blue) -- (magenta) -- (red) -- (yellow) 
    -- (green) edge (black) -- (cyan) edge (blue) -- (white)  edge (magenta) -- (yellow); 
    \draw[thin] (255,0,0) node[left]{255} -- (255,255,0) -- (0,255,0) node[above]{255}
    (0,0,255) node[left]{255} -- (255,0,255) edge (255,0,0)
    -- (255,255,255)  edge (255,255,0) -- (0,255,255)  edge (0,255,0)
    -- cycle ;
    \end{scope}  
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The compile error:

```
File ended while scanning use of \pgfkeys@code.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a version that works. To make it work, I

- removed an extra `)`, i.e. `code args={(#1,#2,#3),#4)}` got replaced by `code args={(#1,#2,#3),#4}` without `)` after `#4`, and
- wrapped `#4` in `"..."`, i.e. `\pgfmathparse{RGBvec(#1,#2,#3,#4)}` became `\pgfmathparse{RGBvec(#1,#2,#3,"#4")}`.

Result:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\def\matPC{{0.257, 0.504, 0.098},% 
    {-0.148, -0.291, 0.439},%
    {0.439, -0.368,0.071}}%
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{RGBvec}{4}{% r,g,b,mat
    \begingroup%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myY}{16+{#4}[0][0]*#1+{#4}[0][1]*#2+{#4}[0][2]*#3}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myCb}{128+{#4}[1][0]*#1+{#4}[1][1]*#2+{#4}[1][2]*#3}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myCr}{128+{#4}[2][0]*#1+{#4}[2][1]*#2+{#4}[2][2]*#3}%
    \edef\pgfmathresult{\myCr,\myCb,\myY}%
    \pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult\endgroup%
}%

\begin{document}
    \tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{110}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[bullet/.style={circle,inner
        sep=2pt,fill},line cap=round,line join=round,
    RGB coordinate/.code args={(#1,#2,#3),#4}{\pgfmathparse{RGBvec(#1,#2,#3,"#4")}%
        \tikzset{insert path={(\pgfmathresult)}}},font=\sffamily,thick]
    \begin{scope}[tdplot_main_coords,scale=1/40]
    \draw[-stealth] (0,0,0) coordinate (O) -- (280,0,0) coordinate[label=below:Cr] (Cr);
    \draw[-stealth]  (O) -- (0,280,0) coordinate[label=below:Cb] (Cb);
    \draw[-stealth]  (O) -- (0,0,280) coordinate[label=left:Y] (Y);
    \path [RGB coordinate={(255,255,255),\matPC}] node[bullet,draw,fill=white] (white){}
    [RGB coordinate={(0,0,0),\matPC}] node[bullet] (black){}
    [RGB coordinate={(255,0,0),\matPC}] node[bullet,red] (red){}
    [RGB coordinate={(0,255,0),\matPC}] node[bullet,green] (green){}
    [RGB coordinate={(0,0,255),\matPC}] node[bullet,blue] (blue){}
    [RGB coordinate={(255,0,255),\matPC}] node[bullet,magenta] (magenta){}
    [RGB coordinate={(255,255,0),\matPC}] node[bullet,yellow] (yellow){}
    [RGB coordinate={(0,255,255),\matPC}] node[bullet,cyan] (cyan){};
    \draw (red) -- (black) -- (blue) -- (magenta) -- (red) -- (yellow) 
    -- (green) edge (black) -- (cyan) edge (blue) -- (white)  edge (magenta) -- (yellow); 
    \draw[thin] (255,0,0) node[left]{255} -- (255,255,0) -- (0,255,0) node[above]{255}
    (0,0,255) node[left]{255} -- (255,0,255) edge (255,0,0)
    -- (255,255,255)  edge (255,255,0) -- (0,255,255)  edge (0,255,0)
    -- cycle ;
    \end{scope}  
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, for item#2, how can we know need to wrapper #4 in "..."?

Comment: @lucky1928 Well, this is not really documented in the manual. The issue is that if the parser sees an ordinary argument, it wants to parse it (and a list `a,b,c` will become something like `{a}{b}{c}` internally) *unless* it is a string. This is why you need to place `"` around the argument of `width`, say, that is, you can say `\pgmathsetmacro{\mywidth}{width("lucky")}` but if you leave out the `"` it won't work. If you want to imply that this could be documented better, I fully agree, you can add an issue at https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues.

Comment: @lucky1928 If you want to know how Iearned about this: a series of failed attempts when setting up a 3d coordinate parser in https://github.com/tallmarmot/pgf/tree/master/experiments/Marmot/3dtools.